# Install Tensorflow GPU 1.0 and keep previous installation of Tensorflow CPU 0.12

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have installed Tensorflow 0.12 cpu-only and I want to install 1.0 GPU without loosing the old version....how can I do that, other than a virtualenv? if I get it...when I import it how do I make distinction ex.: import tensorflow as tf (which one gets imported)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to your distpackages folder (where pip installs tensorflow ) change folder name from tensorflow to tensorflow12. Now install version 1.0 . import tensorflow12 as tf for version 0.12 and import tensorflow for version 1.0. This is just a hack, virtualenv is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also do this on the tf 0.12 folder `find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs  sed -ie 's/tensorflow/tensorflow12/g' `